# How to to find out what species are in each cell?

Tags: vector-grid, species

I have a polygon layer called `grid_trt` which consists of about 100 cells.
[image: Grid layer]

There is a CSV layer as `observation`, which contains GPS coordinates and some information about 2500 species in the form of 25,000 thousand points.

[image: observation points layer]

A portion of the dataset of these points can be found below.

[image: dataset of points]

Now I want to find out what species are in each cell. What method can I use to find out which species are in each cell?

Answer (score 0):

If your point data and your grid data share a coordinate reference system you can do a spatial join on those data.  [See this tutorial for doing spatial joins with QGIS.](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html).